# How to use instr to search with multiple choises?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc, plsql

I wanted to search among multiple columns,so changed it like this from something that only finds names, but now getting `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index :: 2`, so how to solve this?

````
    Text <br /> <input type="text" name="stname" value="${param.stname}"
                       required /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<p />
<c:if test="${!empty param.stname}">
    <sql:query var="students"
               dataSource="${applicationScope.oracleDataSource}">
        select * from students
        where  (instr(upper(stname),?) >= 1 
        OR instr(upper(surname),?) >= 1 
        OR instr(upper(entyear),?) >= 1 
        OR instr(upper(faculty),?) >= 1 
        OR instr(upper(enttype),?) >= 1)
        order by id
        <sql:param value="${param.stname.toUpperCase()}" />
    </sql:query>
```
````

Comment: You now have five input parameters (Oracle will see :1, :2, :3, :4, :5), but you're only supplying one value. You need to send five values.